# Align two different elements

Tags: alignment

I am not able to align these elements, can someone help me please?

Must align on the same line.
Print Problem: http://awesomescreenshot.com/02e1t3ng84

**HTML:**

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink();?  
>;width=100&amp;height=21&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=
like&amp;  show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
style="border:none;  overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" 
allowTransparency="true"></iframe> 

<a title="Compartilhar" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?  
u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank"><img 
src="http://www.fizmarketing.com/Fi2@site/uploads/2013/10/compartilhar-facebook-
e1381288541691.png"></a>
```

I know this is a silly question but please help me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly then you can align **Compartilhar** link using vertical align property.

```
a {
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

This seems to be a **CSS conflict**, check the style properly.